# how to abstract common code in next js (containing returns)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

I have created some custom profile pages that need auth in the dashboard. I want to create about 10 pages with the same duplicated code fragment at the beginning. Just displaying different content later on. Any idea of how to refactor or abstract these functions? I do not want to put it inside the main app component because I have many more public static pages that do not need auth.

Here is the full code of the profile page

```
import {withIronSession} from "next-iron-session";
import logger from "../../lib/logging/logger";
import React from "react";
import Router, {useRouter} from "next/router";
import Layout from "../../components/layout";
import DashboardMenu from "../../components/DashboardMenu";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import {getUserFromSession} from "../../lib/auth/session";

const LoginPage = dynamic(() => import("../login"));

export default function Profile({user}) {
    //this is the start of the common code block
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (user) return; // do nothing if the user is logged in
        Router.replace("/dashboard", "/login", {shallow: true});
    }, [user]);
    logger.debug({info: user, caller: "Profile => user", line: "18"})
    //for some edge case compatibility issues lets do another user check
    if (!user) return <LoginPage/>
    const locale = useRouter().locale
    //common code block ends,
    // there should be locale and user objects accessible here for the rest of the page


    return (
        <Layout lang={locale} backUrl={"/dashboard"}>
            <DashboardMenu user={user}/>
            <div>
            This is your profile / individual content for each secured page
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps = withIronSession(
    async ({req, res}) => {
        const user = getUserFromSession(req)
        //logger.debug({info: user, caller: "Profile => getServerSideProps => user (verify jwt)", line: "42"})
        return {
            props: {user}
        };
    },
    {
        cookieName: "Session2",
        cookieOptions: {
            secure: process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "production",
            maxAge: 72576000,
            httpOnly: true
        },
        password: process.env.APPLICATION_SECRET
    }
);
```